# Stop Infinite Search in my Movie searcher web application

Tags: reactjs

The link for the code is : https://gist.github.com/justgoof9/b0ff1033cc83edeb72c687da0de4f89f

The problem with this is that It keeps on searching it and it never stops. How do I make it so that after the first search it stops?

Comment: Although imposible to know for sure with the code you provided. I would do a wild guess that the problem is, where are you running this code? May be inside the `render` method ? Or any other life-cycle method which is triggered every time you call `setState` ?

Comment: Provide full code for better clarity regarding your problem

Comment: https://gist.github.com/justgoof9/b0ff1033cc83edeb72c687da0de4f89f      There's the full code

Comment: @Nischal did one of these answers solve your problem? If so, you should click the big green check mark next to the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code here https://gist.github.com/justgoof9/b0ff1033cc83edeb72c687da0de4f89f

you are doing search in render and while you `setState` your render is being called again so this is causing infinite search so move that code to lifecycle method like `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const API_KEY = "9f64caf0";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      movies:[],
    }
  }
   componentDidMount(){
     const imdb = require("imdb-api");

      imdb
        .search({ title: "Game Of Thrones" }, { apiKey: API_KEY })
        .then((movies)=>{this.setState({movies})})

        console.log(this.state.movies)

      }

  render() {
      return (
      <div >

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use *componentDidMount* commit lifecycle hook for api calls not render or even *componentWillMount*

From React documentation - https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data

I am Quoting specific lines from the above page.

> There is a common misconception that fetching in componentWillMount lets you avoid the first empty rendering state. In practice this was never true because React has always executed render immediately after componentWillMount. If the data is not available by the time componentWillMount fires, the first render will still show a loading state regardless of where you initiate the fetch. This is why moving the fetch to componentDidMount has no perceptible effect in the vast majority of cases.